# Docker layers with Maven versioning

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, microservices

I have a question with the correct flow for dockerizing Java/Spring Boot/Maven application in order to use docker layers.

Currently it looks like this -> Maven updates the versions(using the maven release plugin) -> docker image is building with the custom dockerfile.

However the problem is, that all of the dependencies are being downloaded every time(even when the poms are not modified, due to the fact, that every new version which I want to build has different version value in the pom's(it is being updated using this plugin).

I would want to use the docker layers, so that our builds could be faster than currently it is. Is it possible to do so? If it is, how? Should I use different plugin or are there other options that should be taken into account(maybe the whole flow is bad and it should be done in a different way?)

Comment: Why are the dependencies downloaded every time? Are you building inside the container and haven't mounted the cache ? Also why not simply using the result (spring boot app) and copy that only into the container?

Comment: We have multi stage dockerfile, which packages application and then copies jar file. The stage with packaging application is problematic, because it downloads all of the necessary dependencies in order to be able to build app.

Comment: As already mentioned the cache is needed and if you don't mount that into your docker image while your are building inside a container (which I usually would prevent) and finally copying the final jar into the docker image...If you like to prevent downloading you have to mount the cache into your docker container

Comment: I will test and come back with the results ;)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to set up a local proxy, like a Nexus or Artifactory instance, which you can use to cache contents from the internet. You'll still be downloading them but hopefully that would be faster.

The second possibility you could do would be to create a Docker layer by downloading the content to the local repository (in the Docker image), followed by then doing a Docker build. So it would look something like:

```
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

RUN mvn build
```

That way, your docker image would capture all of the dependencies and plugins in the local `~/.m2/repository` cache, and then the build would resolve them locally. When you re-run the build step, it should inherit the layer previously.

You'll need to re-build the dependency set over time as your project evolves, but it would speed your build up by not needing them again.

You might want to have a final step that creates a new runtime Docker image from the built contents rather than depending on this layer for all your production content though.

You might want to look at David Delabasee's presentation at QCon London last year:

https://www.infoq.com/presentations/openjdk-containers/

Comment: I was trying to use the multi stage builds with docker but without a success. So still I should copy pom's first, then run mvn dependency:go-offline right? But will it still work even though the version of the application which is in pom's was changed? -> the file has changed so I think that docker will not use the last layer - am I wrong?

Comment: You'll want to do a dependency go-offline first, which will download all your content. If you then add additional dependencies or plugins, they'll be downloaded as usual. As the set increases, you might want to update the Dockerfile to force a rebuild of the dependencies again, but you won't need to do that regularly. But have mvn dependency:go-offline in one RUN, then have the mvn build in another RUN, then do the final copy-to-flattened image afterwards if you want to.

Comment: Ok got it. Just one last question - will that also work for the multi module maven project where we have other submodules dependencies(with their own versions being incremented every time).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to either mount the local maven repository as a volume and use it across Docker images or use a special local repository (/usr/share/maven/ref/) the contents of which will be copied on container startup.

The documentation of the official Maven Docker images ([click here](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven)) also points out different ways to achieve better caching of dependencies.

Comment: I will check it! Thanks for help

Comment: You should use `/root/.m2` and not `/usr/shared/maven/ref/` which is intended for settings configuration etc.